# Adding attributes to a view image field

Tags: views, theming, 8

I want to have this result with views:

```
<image src="http://example.com/sites/example.com/files/blank.gif" data-src="http://example.com/sites/example.com/files/image.jpg" data-retina="http://example.com/sites/example.com/files/image.jpg" />
```

I have a view with hidden image field which formatter is url. I add a global text field in which i add this code

```
<image src="http://example.com/sites/example.com/files/blank.gif" data-src="{{ field_image }}" data-retina="{{ field_image }}" />
```

But it doesn't work. I only have this on the code source of my page

```
<img src="http://example.com/sites/example.com/files/blank.gif"> "http://example.com/sites/example.com/files/image.jpg" data-retina="http://example.com/sites/example.com/files/image.jpg"/>"
```

What am i doing wrong??

Thank you for your help.

Comment: try `{{ field_image|striptags }}`